# Why no error message when extra 'void' is typed before the function call?

Tags: c++

Today I was going to call a function but automatically typed 'void' before the function call. I did not notice, and the compiler did not notice seemingly as well. Thing is that I type 'void' or 'int' so fast that I can do it unintentionally by mistake.

```
void test() {
    cout << "test\n";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void test(); <<-- what is this?
    return 0;
}
```

Above is not my actual code, but a short example. The function is not called though and I had to think why, before I realized that extra 'void' is not rejected by the compiler. Any explanation?

Comment: It's not a function call. It's another function declaration.

Answer (score 3):

`void test();` is a declaration telling the compiler that there is a function called `test`, which takes no arguments and doesn't return anything. It is valid to put these wherever you can "declare stuff" (in other words, wherever you can type `int x;` and it becomes an integer variable called `x`, you can also do `void test();`.

Typically, however, this is done in header files to "publish" functions to other modules, when a particular source file contains a bunch of useful functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It's a forward declaration, same as you might put in an include file.

Comment: "forward" declaration is only used in conjunction with things that you plan to declare later. In this case, it's referring to a function already declared before this point... So it's just a "declaration".